# how to understand file size is more than FILE_MAX_SIZE and send error?

Tags: php

In my form i used two file input and set the MAX_FILE_SIZE for each of them, when i submit form with files bigger than MAX_FILE_SIZE it doesn't do any thing. how can i handle this and report user's files are bigger than max size?
i can do it with a php upload class but when i USE MAX_FILE_SIZE that it didn't work or mybe the class not invoked at all.

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="comp_file">فایل فشرده : </label>
                       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_zipfile_size; ?>" >
                       <input type="file" name='comp_file' class="form-control" id="comp_file">
                       <p class="help-block">فایل قابل دانلود را انتخاب کنبد. 
                       فایل باید در حالتد فشرده قرار داشت باشد.</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="file_image">عکس مربوط به مقاله : </label>
                       <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_image_size; ?>" >
                       <input type="file" name='file_image' class="form-control" id="file_image">
                       <p class="help-block">در صورتی که عکسی مناسب با مقاله در اختیار دارید ارسال کنید.</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: It seems when files are bigger than FILE_MAX_SIZE the submit not set at all.

Answer (score 0):

`MAX_FILE_SIZE` is used on the client side of browser. Therefore, you can't trust it.

When you get the file on the PHP Size, control its size manually:

```
if ($_FILES["comp_file"]["size"] > 1024 * 1024 * 8){ //8mo, adjust as you need
    exit("File too big");
}
```

Obvisouly, this `exit` is a little to harsh. Adapt it to something you need.

Comment: yes i know , but I want double check and with php file sent and after that you can check file size but with MAX_FILE_SIZE you prevent sending file

Comment: MAX_FILE_SIZE is entirely client-side. If the browser doesn't respect it, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Use java script to validate to user for maximum file size uploading,if file size is greater than maximum file size than alert a message to user and stop to submit the action.
or you can check file size at server size and populate an warning message to user by using php itself.